# how can i retrieve the data from a jsp form to the java controller class(the name of input fields are retrieved from the database table

Tags: java, jsp

How can I retrieve the data from a *Jsp form* to the *java controller class*(the name of input fields are retrieved from the database table.

I tried to get that using the `request.getParameter()` method but I cant specify the a particular name of the field in this method as I retrieve the data from the database table in the jsp file

This is the image of the Jsp file from which I try to get the data into the controller class.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B85vv.png)

Comment: Copy paste your code here instead of showing it in image

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the names of the parameters, you can discover them by calling `request.getParameterNames()`, then iterate over each of them to find their values.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Step 1:** Try to create a hidden value that will stash the values of the input elements came from the database.
2. **Step 2:** This hidden value will be populated by javascript / jquery on form submit.
3. **Step 3** Java controller will interact with the hidden field not on the actual elements using request.getParameter("hiddenFieldName");